# Rendering sitecore MVC rendering on an ASPX layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

Does any one has experience implementing hybrid version of Sitecore MVC and webforms?

Sitecore does support the hybrid state but at a page level, meaning either the page has to be on Sitecore MVC layout or ASPX layout, but my requirement is to have a MVC rendering on ASPX layout.

Tried to implement this approach which is available on [web](http://www.hhog.com/blog/sitecore-mvc-components-webforms-pages/#), it does help render the MVC rendering on the page but as soon as a controller action is invoked the partial view rendering shows up without the parent layout as shown in the below snapshot. 
[image]
Due to the above issue, we have decided to have a full page based on MVC layout but it would be good to know if anyone has any experience of such thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog about that.

[Rendering Sublayouts in Sitecore MVC](https://jeffonthecouch.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/rendering-sublayouts-in-sitecore/)

You can also just render a Sitecore MVC page partially and embed the markup into your ASPX page.

[How to Render a Sitecore Placeholder Programmatically](https://jeffonthecouch.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/how-to-render-a-sitecore-placeholder-programmatically/)

Cheers,
Jeff

Comment: Hi Jeff, 

Thank you for your response. But your blog is about rendering the web forms sub-layout on MVC layout/view which is opposite of what I am looking to achieve. 

I am looking to render MVC controller/view rendering on web forms layout. We don't want to convert the existing sub-layouts that are working perfectly fine. The idea is, any new control created should be in MVC rather than .ascx